# Nested Foreach loops to construct datalist from multidimensional array in PHP - issue with nested foreach only repeating first array's values

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a multidimensional array in PHP that I'm trying to construct into an HTML dl list, however Im having issues with the nested foreach only looping through the first value of the first foreach command.

This is the code I'm using.

```
        $content = '<div class="route" data-routeid="'.$route_name.'">';
            foreach ($tripz as $trp){
                $content .= '<dl data-direction="'. $trp['route direction'] .'" data-tripid="'. $trp['trip id'] .'">';  
                    foreach ($timez as $tm){
                        $content .= '<dt>'. $tm['stop name'] .'</dt>';     
                        $content .= '<dd>'. $tm['stop time'] .'</dd>';     
                    }
                $content .= '</dl>';  
            }
        $content .= '</div>';
```

This is the original array:
https://pastebin.com/whj51qHk

and this is the HTML output : https://pastebin.com/KLHU4XyY

Comment: Could you update your question with the values of `$trips` and `$timez`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
foreach ($timez as $tm){
```

With

```
foreach ($trp['times'] as $tm){
```

This way you will get the value from the array you are iterating over.

Comment: That did it!   Thanks